# How to set execute Java code that is in a variable

Tags: java

Let´s say that I have the following variable definition:

```
String strCondition = "x > 0";
```

Is it possible to apply such a condition using the variable "strCondition"?
For example, if I want to use the condition in an "if" statement I would normaly write:

```
if (x > 0)
```

But my issue is that the condition can be anything (x > 0, x <= 10, x == -1, etc).
If I could do something like:

```
if (strCondition)
```

and replace strCondition with its contents to finally process "if (x > 0)"

I hope my question is clear enough. I will appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Java doesn't have a native evaluate (for Java code), there is a `ScriptEngine` (e.g. JavaScript, or Jython, or JRuby, etc) with which you can do such things.

Comment: [The answers to this question will be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2605050/692410)

Comment: How complex will the strings be?

Comment: I agree with the first two comments, although I do want to add one thing:  Always be VERY careful when you write code that will execute the contents of a string that you are not creating some kind of code injection vulnerability.

Comment: Which is why I think a valid approach is to accept a fieldname to test and the value to test against - essentially coding your own very simple scripting.  This will only work if, as @Purag asked, the tests aren't complex, but eliminates the security complications of executing injected code.

Comment: If the conditions are always fairly simple and will be formatted appropriately you could parse the statement out yourself.

Comment: Even **if** you could do this, it would need to do a variable lookup for `x`, which wouldn't be in scope of the evaluation

Comment: You could take a look at Groovy, which supports whitelisted sandboxes for scripts.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  I have a hard time imagining an application that would require a limitless number of expressions.  Most likely, you can write a class to encapsulate the possible tests.  Are all the conditions comparing `x` to a numeric value?